# Найти все заголовки h2 на странице и создать он оглавление

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет. Нужно найти на странице все h2 заголовки и добавить к ним любой id( что бы можно было к ним у перейти)  и создать с них список.  Что бы можно было по клику на оглавление перейти в данному заголовку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const links = [];
[...document.querySelectorAll('h2')].forEach((el, i) => {
 el.id = `h2-${i}`;
 links.push(`<li><a href="#h2-${i}">${el.textContent}</a></li>`);
});
nav.innerHTML = links.join('');
```

```css
section > div {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav"></ul>
<section>
  <h2>Header 1</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis autem quia totam delectus nam at fugiat aliquam tenetur, iste maxime nostrum, suscipit, pariatur aut. Fugiat, vero esse fugit voluptate!</div>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste cum hic error, fugiat, vitae laboriosam sapiente quasi reiciendis nihil aliquam, adipisci reprehenderit sit commodi modi maxime repellat. Deleniti, est, doloremque!</div>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Header 3</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur praesentium culpa esse accusantium obcaecati optio dolore molestiae corporis velit iste nemo iusto sequi, laudantium voluptatem facilis nihil, quod quas quasi.</div>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Header 4</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem molestiae facilis sed dolore rerum id possimus iste. Eaque sequi libero excepturi labore, accusamus doloribus, iure nihil fuga repudiandae tempore aut.</div>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Header 5</h2>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint, veniam reiciendis rerum alias eligendi atque ad commodi beatae, illum enim rem, reprehenderit soluta recusandae perferendis perspiciatis. Saepe iusto, inventore!</div>
</section>
```

P.S. Я бы посоветовал, чтобы в следующий раз вы задавали вопрос более корректно, предоставляя нужный код и крайне желательно, чтобы еще и со своими попытками решения проблемы. В противном случае - закидают помидорами и отвечать не будут. ;)

Comment: Спасибо. Я пробовал и сам на Jquery но не получилось.